# How to exclude a whole paragraph with a regex, leaving the rest of the text untouched?

Tags: regex, logging, error-handling, regex-negation

I have a repeating error message in my app's log output. The error is negligible but it obscures every other important information that the logger logs.

I want to filter it out using a regex (the logger offers a search mechanism which supports regex), but couldn't find the proper pattern. The error message is constant and known.

I tried somethings like this: `(?!^KNOWN_ERROR_MESSAGE$)(^.*$)` but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just try KNOWN_ERROR_MESSAGE and it will catch that phrase anywhere in the log

Comment: No, the point is that I want to catch everything *BUT* KNOWN_ERROR_MESSAGE.